# Inverse of block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

If $C = A + B$ and $D = A - B$,

and $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ and $D , C$ are invertible,

prove the following

$$\begin{bmatrix}A & B \\B & A\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \frac12 \begin{bmatrix}C^{-1} + D^{-1} & C^{-1} - D^{-1} \\ C^{-1} + D^{-1} & C^{-1} - D^{-1}\end{bmatrix}$$

I tried multiplying them I failed (maybe you can),

I did some other work and did not made any thing better.

Glad if you can help.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax. See [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).
Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers.

Comment: @GNUSupporter you are right ,sorry

Comment: $$\begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ B & A \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} A & -B \\ -B & A \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} A^2 - B^2 & -AB + BA \\ BA-AB & -B^2+A^2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @GNUSupporter didnt help that much cause Im new in linear algebra, generally how can Inverse of block matrices be found?

Comment: [See wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion)

Comment: Perhaps you mean $$\begin{bmatrix}A & B \\B & A\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \frac12 \begin{bmatrix}C^{-1} + D^{-1} & C^{-1} - D^{-1} \\ C^{-1} - D^{-1} & C^{-1} + D^{-1}\end{bmatrix}$$.  Substitute $A = 1, B = 0$ to see what happens.